# Implementing css specificity for custom classes based on bootstrap grid breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create my own width classes that make use bootstrap of bootstraps grid breakpoints.
These classes are named things like `w-10, w-20` and would have widths of 10% and 20% respectively, or would have named like `w-sm-10 w-sm-20` and would have widths of 10% & 20% on a screen that has a width larger than `sm`(576px), but would have their initial width on mobile.

Using this snippet I've been able to create classes that have this effect.

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

$i : 10;
@while $i <= 90 {
  .w-#{$i} {              //names like w-40, w-60
    width: #{"#{$i}%"};   
  }
  @each $bp-name, $bp-pixels in $grid-breakpoints {   //looping through xs, sm, md, lg, xl and their pixel values
    .w-#{$bp-name}-#{$i} {  //names like w-md-40
      width: #{"#{$i}%"};
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: $bp-pixels) {       //Remove the width at the corresponding screen widths
      .w-#{$bp-name}-#{$i} {
        width: initial;
      }
    }
  }
  $i : $i + 10;
}
```

---

This solution works as long as my elements only have one of these classes, but breaks when 2 or more are assigned because there is no precedence assigned to any of these classes

Ex. This class should have a width of 50% on screens wider than lg, 70% on screens wider than sm, and a width of 90% on all screen less wide than sm, but instead the div of this width will just always be 90%.

```
<div class='w-lg-50 w-sm-70 w-90'></div>
```

---

I've read a bit about [css-specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) but can't quite wrap my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `max-width` use `min-width` in your media query, it's saying that if your element is at least this wide, then apply this attribute to it.

Also if you use 2 loops, then all the `w-40`, `w-60` classes get defined before the `w-sm-40`, `w-md-40`... classes and the `sm` and `md` classes then take precedence over the prior classes.

In the same way, all the `xs` classes are defined before the `sm` classes, so the `sm` classes take precedence over the `xs` classes and so on through `md`, `lg` and `xl`

```
//Creates width classes like w-40, w-60 ...
$i : 10;
@while $i <= 90 {
  .w-#{$i} {              //names like w-40, w-60
    width: #{"#{$i}%"};   
  }
  $i : $i + 10;
}

@each $bp-name, $bp-pixels in $grid-breakpoints {   //looping through xs, sm, md, lg, xl and their pixel values
  $i : 10;
  @while $i <= 90 {
    @media (min-width: $bp-pixels){ //only works if the screen is wider than this
      .w-#{$bp-name}-#{$i} {  //names like w-md-40
          width: #{"#{$i}%"};
      }
    }
    $i : $i + 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! Could you accept the working answer (and close the question) if it was helpfull

Comment: @LuukSkeur I did. SO actually doesn't let you accept your own answer until 2 days after posting your question